# Cocos2d-x v3.0.0 ListView / ScrollView UI components not working

Tags: listview, scrollview, cocos2d-x

I am using Cocos2d-x v.3.0.0 and trying to use ListView / ScrollView in my Scene.
I am creating the simplest possible ScrollView and add to the current layer.

```
bool MainMenuScene::init() {

    _uiLayer = Layer::create();
    this->addChild(_uiLayer);

    ui::ScrollView* scrollView = ui::ScrollView::create();
    scrollView->setDirection(ui::ScrollView::Direction::BOTH);
    scrollView->setTouchEnabled(true);
    scrollView->setBounceEnabled(true);

    scrollView->setContentSize(Size(500, 1000));
    scrollView->setInnerContainerSize(Size(500, 2000));
    scrollView->setPosition(Vec2(100, 100));

    auto textWidget = ui::Text::create();
    textWidget->setText("Test text");
    textWidget->setFontName("Marker Felt");
    textWidget->setFontSize(100);
    textWidget->setColor(Color3B::BLACK);

    scrollView->addChild(textWidget);

    _uiLayer->addChild(scrollView);

    return true;
```

}

But no matter what attributes I set (background, opacity etc..) every time I get a strange component displayed in my screen with strange colours.

http://speedy.sh/ZQbPX/Screenshot-2014-08-14-15-39-50-2.png

I would appreciate any help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Try with the newest version of Cocos2d-x, I tried your code and everything looks fine.

Comment: I am using Cocos2d-x v3.6. Can someone direct me as to how to use ScrollView that i can see under cocos2d/cocos/ui. I tried $(call import-modue,ui) in my android.mk file. However, whenever it always gives me error cocos2d::ui::ScrollView has not been declared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented a similar ListView. It works fine:

```
Sprite* spr = Sprite::create("sprite.png");
spr->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0, 0.5));
Widget* wid = Widget::create();
wid->setContentSize(spr->getContentSize());
wid->addChild(spr);
view->pushBackCustomItem(wid);
```

try using 
`view->pushBackCustomItem(Widget);`